# How to add jquery fallback for css skew transition?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions, css-animations

I am using on hover css transition. But I need to support min ie 8. I want to add jquery fallback, so that if css transition don’t work, jquery animation will start working. Please check this css skew transition, I need to convert this animation into jquery.

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-wobble-bottom {
  16.65% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-12deg);
    transform: skew(-12deg);
  }

  33.3% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
    transform: skew(10deg);
  }

  49.95% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-6deg);
    transform: skew(-6deg);
  }

  66.6% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(4deg);
    transform: skew(4deg);
  }

  83.25% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-2deg);
    transform: skew(-2deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(0);
    transform: skew(0);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-wobble-bottom {
  16.65% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-12deg);
    transform: skew(-12deg);
  }

  33.3% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
    transform: skew(10deg);
  }

  49.95% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-6deg);
    transform: skew(-6deg);
  }

  66.6% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(4deg);
    transform: skew(4deg);
  }

  83.25% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-2deg);
    transform: skew(-2deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: skew(0);
    transform: skew(0);
  }
}

.hvr-wobble-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.hvr-wobble-bottom:hover, .hvr-wobble-bottom:focus, .hvr-wobble-bottom:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-wobble-bottom;
  animation-name: hvr-wobble-bottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Please someone show me the exact jquery to use. I am not much expert in jquery, so I will really appreaciate if you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) out for the skew, but I don't know that you'll find any fallback for the wobble.  You could try using something like [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/).  But please remember the principal of [graceful degradation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement#Graceful_degradation_and_progressive_enhancement_in_a_nutshell) - cross-browser compatible need not (and often *should* not) mean cross-browser *identical*.